# jQuery .load() with # not working with IE

Tags: jquery

The following code works fine with Chrome and Firefox, but it doesn't work with IE.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.sb-article1').load('inc/latest-articles.asp #article1');
    $('.sb-article2').load('inc/latest-articles.asp #article2');
    $('.sb-article3').load('inc/latest-articles.asp #article3');
    $('.sb-article4').load('inc/latest-articles.asp #article4');
});
```

Here is my markup in the body for the code:

```
<h2>Latest Articles</h2>
<div class="sb-article1"></div>
<div class="sb-article2"></div>
<div class="sb-article3"></div>
<div class="sb-article4"></div>
```

If I have it just like this in IE without my ID, it works:

```
$('.sb-article1').load('inc/latest-articles.asp');
```

But it pulls in all the HTML from latest-articles.asp which I don't want. I'm only looking to grab the partial content from the ID which works fine with Chrome and Firefox. Is there something I'm missing to make this work with IE?

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

The IE version is 8.

In the latest-articles.asp It's just this:

```
<div id="article1">Test1</div>
<div id="article2">Test2</div>
<div id="article3">Test3</div>
<div id="article4">Test4</div>
```

Comment: What's the markup being returned by `inc/latest-articles.asp`?

Comment: Which version of IE ?

Comment: Try using one get instead of all those loads.

Comment: YOur first snippet is VERY inefficient anyways. Just use $.get or $.ajax instead.

Comment: I would suggest only creating a single AJAX request, then pulling-out the specific sections you want in a single event handler, that way you'll create a lot less overhead for your users and your server.

Comment: @Musa - changing it .get breaks it on all browsers.

Comment: @Kevin B - How do you make 4 lines of jquery more efficient?

Comment: the number of lines is irrelevant. A more efficient solution will actually end up being closer to 10 lines. What's inefficient about this is you're making a round trip to the server 4 times to get the exact same data, then you're filtering it down to a part of that data. It would be more efficient to request the data once, then extract all 4 parts from the data at once rather than requesting the data 4 times, once for each part.

Comment: I figured it out... corrupted file.  Fixed it by copy/paste...weird.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out... corrupted file, I think.  I didn't change any of my existing code or markup, I just pasted it into a new HTML file to troubleshoot, and voila, it started working in IE.